# How can I get Quarter To date Vs Previous Quarter to Date in Hive SQL

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

I'm currently using Hive SQL. I know how to get Current Quarter to date, however i'm struggling in getting previous Quarter to date

Example: 
Today is Sept 5th 2017
the current Quarter to date (QTD) is 07/01/2017 - 09/05/2017. (2 months and 5 days)

Now,I would like to get the previous QTD,so it should give me
04/01/2017 - 06/05/2017 (2 months and 5 days). This way i'm comparing apples to apples. the exact same days.

Note: I have an older version of hive sql

For current QTD i'm using:

```
select * from table
where date_col >= printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),),(((month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),)-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1)
AND date_col <= FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Now, for previous QTD I tried using the following: 
The following SQL script gives me 4/01/2017 - today.. but I want to get 4/01/2017 - 06/05/2017 so it is exactly the same days as the current QTD

```
select * from table
where date_col >= printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),),(((month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),)-1) div 6) * 3) + 1,1)
AND date_col <= FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your requirement is still Apples to Apples, because 2months and 5 days that you have mentioned in the description will differ based on the months. For ex: 2 months and 5 days is 63 days for Jan-Mar 5 on a non leap year and it is 66 days for Apr - Jun 5.

Even if you go by number of days, there is huge danger that you spill quarters when you do comparison on june 30 or so.

Assuming its number of days, you have identified most of the solution by yourself, except that you are using FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) as end date.

I would see the solution to be first calculate number of days in this quarter to date, then add it to start date of previous quarter.

```
select date_add(printf('%04d-%02d-
%02d',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),
(((month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))-1) div 6) * 3) + 
1,1),datediff(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),printf('%04d-%02d-
%02d',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),
(((month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1)));
```

I haven't checked the corner cases like month end/quarter end, assumed your logic to be correct.